# invalid model formula in ExtractVars with gam s() wrapper

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

What I am trying to do is simple. I am trying to fit a `gam` model where I can decide the df of the smoothing spline (the `s` function in the formula part). Calling the `gam` model should return the fit, but yet it gives an error. What am I doing wrong here?

```
    library(mgcv)
    library(gam)
    set.seed(2) ## simulate some data... 
    dat <- gamSim(1,n=400,dist="normal",scale=2)
    b <- gam(y~s(x0,df = 5)+s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3),data=dat)
```

Comment: Don't load both the *gam* and *mgcv* packages at the same time. If you want to use `mgcv::gamSim()` but estimate the model with `gam::gam()`, then call `mgcv::gamSim()` but don't load the package (no `library("mgcv")` call). I know the developers have done things to make *gam* work better if *mgcv* is loaded, but it is simpler to avoid any issues and only load one of the packages in any one session.

Comment: yes I noticed..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently was related to the mcgv package and to the version of 'gam'. Using gam '1.14' and not using mcgv worked. Example:

```
    library(ISLR)
    attach(Wage)
    library(gam)
    fit = gam(wage ~ s(year, 4) + s(age, 5) +   education, data = Wage)
    plot(fit)
    summary(fit)
```